# INSERT,GRANT command denied to user 'user'@'host' for table 'table'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I tried to execute a query, but it returned the error `INSERT command denied etc.`.
I googled and I found that I should grant the permission, but it returns me another error!

```
INSERT,GRANT command denied to user 'user'@'host' for table 'table'
```

What should I do?
Thanks `:)`

*PS: I'm Italian, sorry for any error `:(`*

Comment: Well, have you already granted the permission you needed yet?

Comment: You don't have the rights to make these modifications. Contact the guy who can give you permissions.

Answer (score 1):

if you are the admin of this db, have you done:

```
  GRANT INSERT ON db.table TO 'user'@'host';
```

and do not forget to flush privileges?

if you are not the admin you need to contact the admin to do this for you.

Comment: I'm the admin! The database is mine, but I don't know why there is this problem and how to solve!!!

Comment: have you logged into the db as root and tried the above command?